# java array using scanner

Tags: java, arrays

In my program, I want to display an array using `Scanner`, i.e the user enters the array values during runtime.

```
public class NameComparator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the array size is" + n);
        int[] a = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i >= a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = sn.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the value of a[i]" + a[i]);
        }
        sn.close();
        System.out.println("array values are");
    }
}
```

Here, I have got the array size from `Scanner` and then using `for` loop to get each array value, but I don't know why the array block hasn't executed. JVM just skips the `for` loop. `Scanner` works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for(int i=0;i>=a.length;i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```

You want to loop as long as `i` is smaller than `a.length` (i.e. the size of the array).
The for loop will be exited (or skipped) if the termination condition returns `false`. Since you're initializing `i` with `0`, `i>=a.length` (i.e. `0 >= 7`) will be instantly `false`.

Please note, that I've wrote `i < a.length` and not `i <= a.length`. The array size is currently set to `7`, therefore the valid indices are from `0` to `6`. You'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to access index `7`.

And you forgot to use your variable `n` to set the array size:

```
int[] a= new int[n];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues:

```
int[] a= new int[7];//<-- why hard coded?
int[] a= new int[n];// try, you already have array size from user

for(int i=0;i>=a.length;i++)//<-- condition fails, i is 0 for the first time
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++)//try this
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at your for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i>=a.length;i++)
```

Notice that you are using a greater than sign.

Since `i` equals 0, the length of `a` would have to be 0 for this loop to run, and we already know that you declared `a` with a length of 7.

Answer (score 1):

change the below code

```
for(int i=0;i>=a.length;i++) with for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
```

the condition should be `<` instead of `>=`
also use `sn.hasNext()` can simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would do some searching around because there's plenty of questions similar to this.

Regardless, you have a couple things incorrect. You prompt the user for an array size but then throw it out and use 7 instead:

```
    int[] a= new int[7];
```

So, this should be:

```
    int[] a= new int[n];
```

**Second**, your loop condition:

```
for(int i=0;i>=a.length;i++)
```

will be true as long as i is **greater than a,** which will never happen as long as a is a positive integer (because i starts at zero). So, if we're using less than, we should also remember that arrays are zero indexed, so if you input a value of 3, you only want to populate indexes 0, 1 and 2.

So, this should instead be:

```
for(int i=0;i < a.length;i++)
```

Finally, remember to prompt the user, even if this is just a learning exercise it's good practice. Put that all together and you'll get something like this:

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an array size:" );
    int n=sn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("the array size is "+ n);
    int[] a= new int[n];
    System.out.println("Please enter your " + n + "array values:");
    for(int i=0;i < a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]= sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The value of a[" + i  + "] is "  +  a[i]);
    }
    sn.close();

    System.out.println("Array values are " );
    for (int arrayValue : a)
        System.out.println("    " + arrayValue);

}
```